# Custom Attribute that uses Type as a property

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I have the following custom attribute that I would like to have a type name as a property. However, I do not want to have to use the string representation of the type when using the attribute. Example:

```
public class HelpMeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

And to use it, I thought this

```
[HelpMe(TypeName = typeof(MyClass2).FullName]
public class MyClass1
{
}

public class MyClass2
{
}
```

I get the error: "An attribute must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type."

I would prefer not to do:

```
[HelpMe(TypeName = "MyClass2"]
```

because that seems bad to have the type in a string. Better to let the compiler check that the type I am putting in the attribute exists.

Can someone point me down the path of enlightenment to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute initializers can only use compile-time constants or `System.Type` properties.

So why not just use `Type`?

```
public class HelpMeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    ...

    public HelpMeAttribute()
    {
    }
}

...
[HelpMe(Type = typeof(MyClass2))]
public class MyClass1
{
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will compile as is. I think you need to define a constructor that takes the type in and assigns it. But otherwise, it's correct and that's the way I'd do it too. +1

Comment: Any properties of attributes that have a public setter can be set like that. Although yeah, you could do it either way.

Comment: Ahh didn't know that. I actually had tested yours but I had a typo. Had too much wine in me and thought the compiler error was saying it was incorrect syntax. :)